# A small piece of tool fell through the space above the front wheel

Tags: engine

I tried to get it out, but it fell further down. Should I be worried? Can I drive the car as if nothing happened? From the look of it, the space seems to be in the middle of the engine area and the wheel, and there seems to be cover on both sides.

The thing that fell inside was a ring-like object, smaller than palm size, and weighing at most 100g. The bottom line is that I am sure it is overall safe if it just rattles in a confined, secure space.

[image]

Comment: In the case of your question, an image might help of where you dropped it at in the engine bay. Also, "small piece of tool" is rather subjective. How small exactly is a "small piece". And is it actually a tool you dropped, or did a tool break and a piece came off and dropped?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 An image is attached. I have encircled the crack it fell through as well.

Comment: There are more than a few sockets, etc, riding around in cars. I found a good box wrench in one frame member.

Comment: If it is ferrous metal you can probably retrieve it with a telescoping magnet, it's an essential in every mechanic's toolbox just for this reason.

Comment: @blacksmith37 - there is a story I heard of a British guy who bought an Armstrong Siddeley Sapphire, a kind of 'poor man's Rolls-Royce'. He found there was an odd knocking sound from time to time, mainly when turning. He found out why after a collision when a welded bodywork section was opened up to reveal a large nut suspended on a length of fishing line and a note reading 'So you found it'. Also stories of British Leyland era Minis with a handful of self tapping screws put into doors before welding up. Bad industrial relations to blame in both cases I think.

Comment: @apen Can you do a bigger circle? Preferably red, hand drawn. I really can't see the circle.

Comment: @GdD unless the magnet just finds a bit of car to stick to first, as with the spanner in my van door (I'd use a magnet on a rigid stick but there isn't quite a straight line) or the tool will only fit through the gap in an orientation it's unlikely to be picked up.

Comment: I guess the question is - how badly do you want that part back?  Also, how dangerous would this object be if it were to be run over by another driver?  It's likely that it'll fall out on the road when driving, so you might be inadvertently leaving a caltrop for the car behind you...

Comment: @MichaelHarvey the stories of stuff intentionally left in 70s Detroit iron are apocryphal. Beer cans, nuts, bolts, whatever...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This area isn't going to pose you an issue. The worst which may happen is if it starts rattling. Other than that, it's all good and shouldn't pose any issues.

Comment: Ultimately, I took it out by taking off the piece of plastic near the back of the front wheel. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @apen - Awesome! Glad you were finally able to retrieve the piece. :o)